# How do I calculate logrithmic labels for a VU meter scale?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, canvas, html5-canvas

I writing a meter widget using canvas and need to calculate the label values for the scale. No problem except when I'm trying to re-create the scale for a VU meter. I understand it's logrithmic, but the values aren't powers of 10 on that type of meter.

see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VU_meter

The function I have is given the min and max values for the scale. For normal scales, it also is given the step between values. For example, given -20 and 30 with a step of 10, it would produce labels:

-20 -10 0 10 20 30

For a VU meter given -20 and 6, I need to produce labels:

-20 -10 -5 -3 0 3 6

And, the spacing isn't the same on the scale between those values.

I am not asking for actual code examples, but instead for ideas on how to best approach implementing this.

Should I write the function so one of the parameters is a list of labels, then plot them on a logarithmic scale? That doesn't appear to work properly because the numbers do not end up in the right places as seen in the image above of a proper VU meter.

Is there some special formula just for dB levels that isn't a simple log function?

Again, I'm not asking for code examples, just for some help understanding the best approach to use.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems more a math question ... Maybe try here: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just note that in the digital domain max is 0 dB (anything above is clipped).

Comment: Please can you tell me that why did you reject my this edit(https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16614567) ? I tried to find a email address or any other way to contact you. But I could not. STha's why A asked it as a comment.  I could not understand the meaning of "This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive".

Comment: You should have replied/commented and let the OP make the change. Instead you altered their post. Probably could have been flagged as "Attempt to Reply" or :"Not the Authors Original Intent"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you have a value-to pixel function. What you need to write is the *inverse* function of that.

When you have the inverse function, you just divide the screen area to N equal parts (in the picture you have 6 regions). One region will be X pixels in width. Now you can use your inverse function to get the value for that pixel-position.

This will not be an integer, it will be something like 3.434 or 11.34 - you need a prettyfier function which will generate the closest "pretty" number (let's say just chop off the parts after the decimal).

Now you take the pretty value and calculate the pixel position for it with your original function.

Some code:

```
function value2px(value, valueMin, valueMax, pxMin, pxMax) {
    var valueWidth = sigLog(valueMax) - sigLog(valueMin);
    var pixelWidth = pxMax - pxMin;
    var ratio = pixelWidth / valueWidth;

    return ratio * (sigLog(value) - sigLog(valueMin)) + pxMin;
}

function px2value(px, valueMin, valueMax, pxMin, pxMax) {
    var valueWidth = sigLog(valueMax) - sigLog(valueMin);
    var pixelWidth = pxMax - pxMin;
    var ratio = pixelWidth / valueWidth;

    return sigExp((px - pxMin) / ratio + sigLog(valueMin));
}
```

and the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/ambcwoLg/1/

Comment: The fiddle made a lot of sense. Instead of pixel position (x axis), I'll use the needle angle in case the scale is an arc as in the picture. I did notice that the 0 value seems to be missing, but that's a minor issue I'll be able to sort out. The value2px is sort a "percent of scale", but based on a log scale rather than linear scale, if I understand your code correctly. The same function would return the needle angle as well. Thanks for the example and the explanation!

Comment: I chose pixels for the simplicity, but this should work for angles as well (or any linear scale). You can play around with the *beautify* function (codify that you prefer 10 to 9 and 5 to 4). Also for dB you will need a 10-based log, the example uses an E-based one (Math.log's default).

Comment: I changed the trunc to a ceil and the numbers matched up with the example photo. I've adapted your functions to my gauge so now it can figure the needle position when given a "proper" vu value and it works with straight and arc'd scales. The math part had me really hung up, and your example explained a lot. I also modified one function so that it would calculate the position for zero correctly. **Thanks!**

Comment: One problem I ran into is that log and log10 don't return values for numbers between -1 and 1, so while the code above allows me to generate the labels for the scale, they don't work when calculating the needle position (for values between -1 and 1, inclusive).

Comment: True. But you can use lg(1 + n). I changed the sample code to 10-based and implemented the +1 (and -1) in the sample code. http://jsfiddle.net/ambcwoLg/1/

Comment: can you explain the mathematical background of the sigLog function? I can't fully comprehend what you are doing there...

Comment: @bob it achieves three things: you only calculate logs on positive numbers (the original sign will be added back as a last step), you only calculate logs on numbers x > 1 (because the log function works differently in the region 0 < x < 1) and finally it lets you get base-10 (or any other) logs instead of the build-in (natural) base.

Comment: how can I adjust this code so that the space between different values is equal e.g. if I want the space between -10 dB and -5 dB nearly equal and I also just go up to 0 dB?

Comment: @bob The heart of this solution is to sacrifice the even spacing for nicer numbers. You can have a prettify function like this `return Math.round(n * 10) / 10;` and have more even spacing.